# Spring Boot 2+ providing custom TypeLocator to SPeL

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-el

How do I provide a custom TypeLocator to SpEL in spring boot 2? I don't want to type fully-qualified names when using custom security expression. 
I've overridden:
SecurityExpressionRoot and DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler.